# Gradle Cannot Find Integration Test, JUnit 5 and Spring Boot: No tests found for given includes:

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit5

When I run:

```
./gradlew  :integrationTest --tests com.shohidulhaque.whatdoyouthinkauthorizationservice.WhatdoyouthinkauthorizationserviceApplicationTests2
```

I get the following output:

```
No tests found for given includes: [com.shohidulhaque.whatdoyouthinkauthorizationservice.WhatdoyouthinkauthorizationserviceApplicationTests2](--tests filter)
```

I am confident that I have setup the build.gradle properly.

I have uploaded this project to github. It can be found at https://github.com/shohidulhaque/integrationTestRepo

I would be grateful if any one could help on this.
I am using:

Gradle 6.4.1
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java-library'
}

group = 'com.shohidulhaque'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
}


sourceSets {
    integrationTest {

        groovy.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integrationTest/groovy"
        resources.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integrationTest/resources"
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {

    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'

    testImplementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '3.0.4'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'

    testImplementation (group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0')
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have got this working by modifying the integrationTest to:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

This will enable JUnit 5. I think by default it enables Junit 4 and this does not recognise the some of annotation used for testing a Spring Boot application.

Comment: you are an angel sent from heaven!

Comment: bacon. saved. thx